# How to retrieve statusCode from ApiKit mapping in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

We want to process all of the exceptions we catch with the same process in our exception strategy. It is the one generated by apikit. We first send a lot with a custom component and then we generate json response. In the response with DataWeave we want to set the same statusCode. However, the statusCode do not seem to be a variable that is retrievable. Am I correct, or there is a good way to retrieve it?

```html
    <apikit:mapping-exception-strategy xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" name="svc0031_hotel-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping">
         <apikit:mapping statusCode="504">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException"/>
            <flow-ref name="svc0031_manageErrors" doc:name="Manage Error"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
  <apikit:mapping statusCode="404">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException"/>
            <flow-ref name="svc0031_manageErrors" doc:name="Manage Error"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
    </apikit:mapping-exception-strategy>
    <sub-flow name="svc0031_manageErrors">
        <set-payload value="#[groovy:message.exceptionPayload.rootException.message]" doc:name="Set BIP Payload"/>
        <custom-transformer class="se.zystems.baseline.BaselineLogging" doc:name="Log BIP Outgoing">
            <spring:property name="Level" value="ERROR"/>
            <spring:property name="ObjectId" value="CatchErrors"/>
            <spring:property name="TransactionStatus" value="failed"/>
        </custom-transformer>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{ 
  status : 400,
  message : payload,
  code : 42,
  more_info :"https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/nordic-choice-hotels"
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </sub-flow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out where the statusCode value is stored thanks to the answer by [Jesús Pablo Fernández](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6561602/jes%C3%BAs-pablo-fern%C3%A1ndez)

He was almost right in his answer, however, the statusCode is stored not in message.inboundProperties['http.status'], but in message.outboundProperties['http.status']. No need to even extract a variable, one can just access it in data transformer directly like this:

```html
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{ 
  status : outboundProperties['http.status'],
  message : payload,
  code : 42,
  more_info :"https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/nordic-choice-hotels"
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
```

Answer (score 2):

Good,

If you create a variable with the http.status then you can use it in the mapper:

```
 <flow name="test">
        <set-variable variableName="httpStatus" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status']" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json

---
{ 
  status : flowVars.httpStatus,
  message : payload,
  code : 42,
  more_info :"https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/nordic-choice-hotels"
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
    </flow>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the apikit:mapping statusCode="value" is not passed in message.inboundProperties['http.status'] thus cannot be used later on in the flow.

Comment: You were almost right though, check my answer please.Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Status codes defined in the APIKitExceptionStrategy will be those sent back in the response header as http.status given the corresponding exception to be raised.
For instance,

```
<apikit:mapping statusCode="504">
        <apikit:exception value="org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException"/>
        <flow-ref name="svc0031_manageErrors" doc:name="Manage Error"/>
    </apikit:mapping>
```

means that when a *org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException* exception is thrown and caught by this exception block, then a 504 status code is sent back as a response header. 
If you want to bypass the statusCode attribute in the APIKit exception block, you should have another exceptionStrategy block to catch your desired exception, and then you could set your status code like that

```
<set-property name="http.status" value="<the_desired_status, e.g. 401>" />
```

Hope it helps.

/Tony

Answer (score 0):

Good Stanislav Ivanov,

I have a flow implemented with the APIKit, which is the code that I attach and whether there is property in the inboundProperties http.status, review it because if it should contain the value, if you do not have your flow may modify the value in a previous step.

I pointed him to directly access the outboundProperties in the mapper, I was not aware, thank you very much.

Comment: I am glad if it helped! Thanks and have a nice weekend!